# Cutting out existing steel duct in bathroom vent

Tags: brick, exhaust-fan, exhaust

I'm enlarging my bathroom vent. It's a brick wall and currently has a steel duct. I've chipped away brick but the lip of the existing steel duct is still there. I need to remove around 2 inches of it. Any suggestions best way to cut that off?

[image: photo 1]
[image: photo 2]

Comment: Posting a well focused photo or two would be really helpful for this question.

Comment: Fair enough, done

Comment: If you don't mind trashing the pipe, you could grab the end with pliers and twist it towards the center. You'd probably have to remove the whole pipe, though.

Answer (score 2):

One way to cut away the excess metal would be to use a rotary Dremel type tool with abrasive cutoff wheels. This method allows the metal to be removed without bending and deformation that other cutting methods would typically cause.

If you go this route be prepared to use up a good sized quantity of the cutting wheels. When I am using my rotary tool and have a large amount of cutting to do I have about ten of the mandrels that hold the cutting wheels preloaded with cutting disks. This way when  one wears down or breaks I can quick load another mandrel into the chuck on the rotary tool and continue cutting.